# using quotename and order by that column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a date table. The query below (in between the declare and print statements) returns the last working date of each month.

The problem I have is that I want these dates to be stored in my variable @dates but ordered. The code below works however if I put an order by Date after the group by line the code will not execute because,

> Column "myTbl.Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
declare @dates nvarchar(max) = ''

select @dates = @dates + QUOTENAME(max(Date)) + ','
from myTbl
where IsWeekend = 0
group by MMYYYY

print(@dates)
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with expected output from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to recommend this method of string concatenation.  But your problem is the ordering.

Just use the aggregated value:

```
order by max(date)
```

In the most recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select string_agg(quotename(max_date), ',') within group (order by max_date
from (select max(Date) as max_date
      from myTbl
      where IsWeekend = 0
      group by MMYYYY
     ) t;
```

In earlier versions, use `for xml path`:

```
select @dates = stuff( (select ',' + quotename(max(Date)) 
                        from myTbl
                        where IsWeekend = 0
                        group by MMYYYY
                        order by max(Date)
                        for xml path ('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Gordon.

However, if you wanted to keep the same structure, you store your dates in a temp table and order that. See below:

```
select *
into #test 
from #temp
order by dates desc 


declare @dates nvarchar(max) = ''

select @dates = @dates + QUOTENAME(max(dates)) + ','
from #temp
group by dates

print(@dates)
```